# LWUIT HtmlComponent render local image

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit, html-components

I want to render content that i have created locally using html component and put image in this html also by putting image in `res` folder in jar, i tried

`<img src='images/down.png'></img>`

`<img src='res/images/down.png'></img>`

`<img src='./images/down.png'></img>`

but nothing worked, any suggestion?

**[EDIT]**
here is my code, i have no idea how to implement `DocumentRequestHandler` that is why i used `DefaultDocumentRequestHandler`

```
        DocumentRequestHandler handler = new DefaultDocumentRequestHandler();
        HTMLComponent component = new HTMLComponent(handler);
        component.getStyle().setBorder(Border.createLineBorder(1));

        component.getSelectedStyle().setBorder(Border.createLineBorder(1));
        component.setBodyText("<div><b>nirmal:</b>" +
                "<img src='res://images/down.png' /></div>");
```

tried `res://images/down.png` but nor worked
my image is in `res/images`

Comment: can you give the code from creating and using the HtmlComponent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explain how you loaded the HTML, images are loaded relatively to the base URL so you need to define the base URL when creating the HTML (its implicitly detected when loading via URL).

If you created the HTML via `setHTML(String)` then you need to give absolute paths depending on your DocumentRequestHandler implementation e.g. `res://myImage.png` or `file://myImage.png` .